# Payfort CORS Error Payment API

Tags: javascript, cors, payfort

Integrating Payfort from client side but I am getting CORS error on second step.
Have done this integration using ASP.Net and it worked fine.

Is it that payfort does not support client side integration?
Below is the response
[image]

Below is the code

```
 _getAPIData = (paymentData) => {
    var apiData = {};
    apiData.command = paymentData.cmsData.command;
    apiData.currency = paymentData.currency;
    apiData.eci = paymentData.cmsData.eci;
    apiData.amount = paymentData.price;
    apiData.token_name = parseQueryString("token_name");
    apiData.merchant_reference = paymentData.merchantReference;
    apiData.customer_email = paymentData.cmsData.customerEmail;
    apiData.customer_ip = paymentData.cmsData.customerIP;
    apiData.remember_me = paymentData.cmsData.rememberMe;
    apiData.access_code = paymentData.cmsData.accessCode;
    apiData.merchant_identifier = paymentData.cmsData.merchantIdentifier;
    apiData.language = paymentData.language;
    apiData.return_url = paymentData.cmsData.interMediatePageUrl2;
    apiData.signature = paymentData.signature;

    return apiData;
}
_get3dUrl = (paymentData) => {
    let apiData = this._getAPIData(paymentData);
    let payfortConfig = {
        method: "POST",
        url: paymentData.cmsData.payFortUrl2,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        },
        data: apiData
    }
    debugger;
    // return api.platformService(payfortConfig);
    return axios(payfortConfig);
}
```

Comment: "Is it that payfort does not support client side integration?" — You could try asking them.

Comment: Ya, exactly that's my question.And if it does I wanted to showcase a little code for reference to know if there is something wrong on my part.

Comment: You will see that the portion between quote marks is where I am quoting you. Try reading the rest of the comment.

Comment: Yes, definitely I will ask them but this is what this platform is for if someone has already faced a similar issue I can avoid that back and forth anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't use AJAX for that, payfort needs to show the payment page... Even if you got the response back, what did you expect to do with it?

Comment: Just had a word with a Payfort guy they want it to be a complete form POST and not an ajax post.
@Salketer : I was expecting to redirect using to the 3d url by getting that data in response.I guess I am sorted will try the form post and update this question.